# Two multi-curves in a surface with the same transverse measure

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, curves-and-surfaces, foliations

Let $(\cal F,\mu)$ be the stable measured foliation of a pseudo-Anosov on an oriented surface $S$. Can there be two non-isotopic multi-loops (collections of disjoint simple loops) $L_1,L_2\subset S$, both transverse to $\cal F$ with the same transverse measure, $\mu(L_1)=\mu(L_2)$?

If yes, how one can construct such example?

PS. One can prove that "transversely isotopic"="isotopic" in this setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  For example, by lifting - there are other constructions, as well.

---

Here are the details of a lifting construction. Suppose that $f$ is a pseudo-Anosov on a surface $T$.  Pick a simple closed curve $\alpha$ in $T$.  Choose a double cover $S$ of $T$ where the preimage of $\alpha$ has two components.

There is some power $k \in \mathbb{N} - \{0\}$ so that $f^k_* \colon \pi_1(T) \rightarrow \pi_1(T)$ preserves the subgroup $\pi_1(S)$.  Thus $f^k$ lifts to $S$.  Let $g$ be any one such lift; note that $g$ is pseudo-Anosov on $S$.

Finally, the two lifts of $\alpha$ to $S$ have the desired property with respect to the stable measured foliation of $g$.

Comment: Thanks, Sam! That is exactly what I was looking for. May I be greedy and ask you what are the other constructions you mentioned?

Comment: Well, it is "easy" to randomly build examples, using Mark Bell's program flipper (say).  For example, in $S = S_{1,2}$ we can find three curves $a, b, c$ all of which meet (exactly once) at a single point, and the anti-clockwise order at that point is $a,b,c,a,b,c$.  If we take the product $abC$ of two right twists and one left twist, we get a pA map where the dilatation is $2 + \sqrt{3}$.  The degree is two, which is one lower than the dimension of $\mathcal{PML}(S)$.  So we can hope for some coincidences... and actually looking at the example we do find such coincidences.

Comment: Oops - that should be $\mathcal{ML}(S)$, not $\mathcal{PML}(S)$.  Hmm.  Now that I think about it, it is obvious that my original answer is a very special way to construct pA maps whose degree is small compared to complexity of the ambient surface.  But the lifting construction forces a symmetry, which forces the coincidence to happen.  "Low degree" pA maps do not, in general, need to have a symmetry.